# How to handle Internal server error when XSS attacks on application for NETSPARKER ENTERPRISE SCAN REPORT

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Asp.Net MVC application
When user tries to submit HTML or JavaScript code in query string of action method , getting Internal server error(500) with below exception..

```
A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (userid="'"-->..script..").
```

I have enabled the custom error mode so that end user is redirecting the custom error page for any XSS attacks.

But when I run NETSPARKER ENTERPRISE SCAN against action method with javascript code in query string , report coming as Internal server error - The server responded with an HTTP status 500.

What is the best practice to handle this internal server issue.

Comment: please post action code or attribute and more info on mvc version you using and what example of query failing

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion: Custom Error handler**

I am not sure about best practice, but what I use is `<customErrors>` in the `web.config` to redirect the user to a "nice" web page. The page it redirects to can be a plain HTML, ASPX etc. The nice thing is that you can setup a default custom error page, plus individual ones based on HTTP Status Code.

Follows is a snippet from my `web.config` for a default error code handler, plus one for HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error) which is what you are getting for the `A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected` error:

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect" defaultRedirect="~/dangitall.html">
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/dangitall500.html" />
</customErrors>
```

`dangitall.html` is a standard HTML page for all error. Its overridden by `dangitall500.html` which will display for HTTP 500 errors. The contents of these HTML pages can be whatever you want: warn the user, abuse the user etc :)

Follows is a link to the Microsoft tech article regarding custom errors and all of the possible attribute settings etc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.customerror?view=netframework-4.8